# Is there a function in PostgreSQL that counts string match across columns (row-wise)

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, count, lateral-join

I want to overwrite a number based on a few conditions.

**Intended overwrite:**
If a string (in the example I use is just a letter) occurs across 3 columns at least 2 times **and** the numerical column is more than some number, overwrite the numerical value **OR**
If another string occurs across 3 columns at least 2 times **and** the numerical column is more than some other number, overwrite the numerical value, **else** leave the numerical value unchanged.

The approach I thought of first, works but only if the table has one row. Could this be extended somehow so it could work on more rows? And if my approach is wrong, would you please direct me to the right one?

Please, see the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/51d79e/1)

Any help is highly appreciated!

if letter **a** repeats **at least** **2** times among **section_1,section_2,section_3** and **number** **>= 3**  then overwrite **number** with **3** or if letter **b** repeats **at least** **2** times among **section_1,section_2,section_3**  and **number** **>= 8** write **8**, else leave **number** unchanged

```
CREATE TABLE sections (
id int,
section_1 text,
section_2 text,
section_3 text,
number    int
 );

INSERT INTO sections VALUES
( 1, 'a',  'a',  'c', 5),
( 2, 'b',  'b',  'c', 9), 
( 3, 'b',  'b',  'c', 4);
```

[image]

expected result:
**id  number**
1      3
2      8
3      4

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a `case` expression?

```
select (case when (section_1 = 'a')::int + (section_2 = 'a')::int + (section_3 = 'a')::int >= 2 and
                  other_col > threshold
             then 'special'
        end)
```

You can have additional `when` conditions.  And include this in an `update` if you really wand to change the value.

Comment: Thank you! It is so compact and pretty, thank you very much :)

Comment: Another option to count the matches: `cardinality(array_positions(array[section_1, section_2, section_3], 'a'))`

Answer (score 1):

A typical solution uses a lateral join to unpivot:

```
select s.*, x.number as new_number
from sections s
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) number
    from (values (s.section_1), (s.section_2), (s.section_3)) x(section)
    where section = 'a'
) x;
```

This is a bit more scalable than repeating conditional expression, since you just need to enumerate the columns in the `values()` row constructor of the subquery.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, indeed it is a working solution, thank you very much for that! The only problem is that I don't understand the code and I would need more time to decipher it, which of course, I'll gladly do. Thank you once again! -All the best,